# Resize and move window, using python

Tags: python, windows

So I need to launch chrome from within Python (Preferably as a new window, not a tab), and then resize the window, move it and go to a specific URL.

I think I almost have it, it just won't launch chrome.

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.start("Chrome.exe")
dlg_spec = app.window()
dlg_spec.move_window(x=None, y=None, width=500, height=500, repaint=True)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem, and here is my process:

- I went on discord (Python channel) and asked for suggestion, and someone wrote: "use selenium".
- After a ton of google, reading, and youtube videos here is my solution.
- Watch this video if you have trouble with the web driver for selenium.
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3tYiyE_OXE

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_window_position(0,375)
driver.set_window_size(1920,705)
driver.get('https://dk.docendo.dk/calendar#/')
```

This code will do the following:

- Import web driver
- Get the web driver for chrome
- Launch chrome
- Move chrome window to given coordinates
- Resize the windows
- Go to the suggested URL

Hope this helps someone!